# Character Encoding Problem

Tags: iphone

I am facing a problem of character encoding. when i am posting data with special character all the things after the special character are not post to server.How do to convert special characters?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This can be many things but a few things you can try:

1) Try base64 encoding it to make sure the full thing posts to the server. Of course you would have to un-base64 it on the server. (helps if content is binary especially)

2) Make sure you aren't posting unicode/ascii differences, make sure the app, webpage and server expect the same type.  Also make sure if using a webpage that they don't have conflicting header types.

3) Convert symbols to html sybmols i.e. `©` to `&copy;` if it is just html. Most languages have an HtmlEncode type feature.

You can set the type in an HTTP post: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1` or in the header of the html file if posting from a local UIWebView and embedded resource: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

It is possible the difference in encoding makes it think the content is ended after the special symbol thus the cut off.

More info on what type of app and how you are posting would help.